# First mvn compile fails to find generated sources

Tags: java, maven, annotation-processing

I use an annotation processor that creates sources in `target/generated-sources/annotations/`

When these generated sources don't exist I get an error if I run `mvn compile`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project project-name: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /path/src/main/java/org/acme/dao/SomeClass.java:[39,19] cannot find symbol
```

It fails, but it creates the sources, so if I run `mvn compile` again it works.

Is there a plugin/configuration that I can add to `pom.xml` so it works the first time, please?

Here's the section of my `pom.xml` that might be relevant:

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>some-group</groupId>
                            <artifactId>some-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations/</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                              <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                      <goal>parse-version</goal>
                                      <goal>add-source</goal>
                                      <goal>maven-version</goal>
                                      <goal>add-resource</goal>
                                      <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                                      <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                  <action>
                                    <execute>
                                      <runOnConfiguration>true</runOnConfiguration>
                                      <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                  </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: Can you add the compile plugin and annotation processor parts of your pom.xml to the question?

Comment: Please post the full pom file ...otherwise it's hard to even guess what could be wrong...

Comment: Hi @slindenau I added the build part of my pom.xml

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise I added the build part of my pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem here:
https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/6500306/#Comment_6500306

I basically split the compiler execution and ignore the failure of the first compilation (compilation should not happen anyway).
So the important piece here is `<failOnError>false</failOnError>`:

```xml
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process-annotations</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                            <compilerArgs>
                                <arg>-proc:only</arg>
                                <arg>-implicit:none</arg>
                                <arg>-processor</arg>
                                <arg>com.github.tivrfoa.mapresultset.MappingProcessor</arg>
                            </compilerArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerArgs>
                                <arg>-proc:none</arg>
                            </compilerArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

It's not exactly the solution that I wanted, but it does the job.
I had to this way because `javac` is not respecting `-proc:only`

But maybe I'm missing something. Let's hope someone has a better answer. =)

Answer (score 0):

the "modern" way to plug annotation processors in ~recent (>5 years old) jdk and maven is following:

```xml
<dependencies>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some-group</groupId>
        <artifactId>some-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

i.e. just add annotation processor as a dependency with `scope=provided` and remove outdated configurations.